# Distinguish which link-button clicked in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have that html code:

```
<form id="my-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'my_view' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="md-form mb-1">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="md-form mb-1">
        <textarea id="message_then" name="message_then" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="text-center text-md-left">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('my-form').submit();" style="width: 78px;" name="name1">Click1</a>
</div>
<div class="text-center text-md-left">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('my-form').submit();" style="width: 78px;" name="name2">Click2</a>
</div>

</form>
```

Now I would like to get to know which "button" was clicked. Unfortunately `request.POST` doesn't have that information.

Comment: The `click event` is not added to the `POST` dict in Django. You can handle this use case with `javaScript` i guess

Comment: @Rvector Thank you. However, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You could add a hidden field to your form and then instead of just doing a document.getElementByID(...).submit() you would have a js function that changes the value of the hidden field and then calls the form's submit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another field to specify which button has been clicked.

Exp:
Add this to your form

then update your "a" elements onclick event code like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update_form(this)" style="width: 78px;">Click1</a>
```

And finally some js code to update the form

```
<script>
 function update_form(button){
     document.getElementById("id_button").value = document.getElementById(button).innerText;
     document.getElementById('my-form').submit();
 }
</script>
```

In your django view use this to get the selected button:
request.POST['id_button']